# Which thread to call CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, nsrunloop

I'm running `CFRunLoopRun()` in **Thread A**. To terminate the run loop, should I come back to **Thread A** to call `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())`?

What happen if I call `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())` in **Thread B**? If I'm in **Thread B**, how could I come back to **Thread A** to perform this call?

Sorry for this basic question. I just switched from Android to iOS and face a lot of context switch...

Thanks!

Comment: This is very low level - what are you trying to achieve? If you aren't familiar with the Cocoa frameworks then you may have missed an easier method.

Comment: Legacy codes...... Happened to jump into them...

Comment: Ouch. Well here's a question where someone asked something similar and got an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1363787/558933

Comment: In what context are you calling CFRunLoopRun()?  An NSThread subclass?

Comment: @RoboticCat I read that post. My understanding is each thread would have its own run loop. If we can get the RunLoop reference from Thread A, we can call `CFRunLoopStop(RunLoopOfThreadA)` in Thread B. But we cannot call `CFRunLoopStop(CFRunLoopGetCurrent())` since it will stop the RunLoop on Thread B if there is any. Please correct me if I miss something...

Comment: @CharlesA. In some worker thread from a library we are writing... At first I used `NSRunLoop`, but I changed it to `CFRunLoopRun` since I didn't find a stop method on `NSRunLoop`. However, they seem to refer to the same object under the hood even though they cannot be cast to each other with toll free.

Comment: Yeah, CFRunLoop and NSRunLoop are indeed similar.  I was actually asking about what type of thread the run loop is running on.  NSThread?  POSIX thread?

Comment: @CharlesA.I believe it is POSIX thread, since most of the codes are C++.

Comment: @Hackjustu Then you may want to reference that question linked above by Robotic Cat.  The selected answer mentions creating a source for the run loop so that you can signal the source to get it to stop the run loop.  It's discussed in a document linked from the selected answer.  If it was an `NSThread`, you could use `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`, but that doesn't do any good with POSIX threads.

Comment: @CharlesA.Nice! It works and I just found if I use `NSRunLoop`, I don't even need to call `CFRunLoopStop`. Just trigger a method on `Thread A` then the loop will stop.

Comment: @CharlesA. Would you mind putting your solution as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: The `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:` suggestion, I assume?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `POSIX` threads, then you should definitely follow [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1363787/558933) provided in the comment by @Robotic Cat.  It points to a document that describes adding a source to the `CFRunLoop` that can be triggered to stop the run loop.

If you are using `NSThread` subclasses, and you have a handle to the one you want to stop, you should be able to create a method on that `NSThread` subclass that stops the `CFRunLoop` with the code you noted above and invoke it with `performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:`.